# What went wrong with this driver install?

Tags: opensuse, make

I am trying to install [the correct LAN card drivers](http://code.google.com/p/r8168/downloads/detail?name=r8168-8.031.00.tar.bz2&can=2&q=) on openSuse 12.1. This is the output of the log file for the `autorun.sh` script:

```
-------------------------------
Sun Jul  1 21:50:45 IDT 2012
-------------------------------
Sun Jul  1 21:59:26 IDT 2012
make -C src/ clean
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/shelly/r8168-8.031.00/src'
make -C /lib/modules/3.1.0-1.2-desktop/build SUBDIRS=/home/shelly/r8168-8.031.00/src clean
make: Entering an unknown directory
make: Leaving an unknown directory
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/shelly/r8168-8.031.00/src'
```

How can I figure out what went wrong?

Comment: Uh, you want to know what went wrong with a *clean* operation?

Comment: After running `autorun.sh` the card still doesn't work, so I assumed that the install failed.

Comment: The clean operation doesn't build, much less install.

Comment: The `autorun` script did not continue after the `clean` operation. Why? Something went wrong. What might that have been? Other than the log I don't have any other information to provide. It is a clean 12.1 install with an ASUS P8H61-M LX motherboard that cannot access the internet due to not having the LAN driver installed.